# Sharing frontend components between private projects

Tags: javascript, git, npm, bower, frontend

In the organisation I work in, we have a couple of web and mobile projects that are built differently but share similar custom built frontend components. Currently the structure we follow is to store the code for the web and mobile projects in the same repository like:

```
/root
--/web
--/mobile
--/shared_components
```

However, this doesn't appear to be a model that would scale properly. Both projects would have to be managed individually.

I thought of creating the shared components as a bower component and adding the necessary bower.json files in the two repos, but the components are meant to be private. I also thought of using the git subtree feature, but I would prefer something that doesn't get as complex as that (especially since most of the team members are just getting used to git). I have also thought of node modules but that still poses the same problem with bower.

Would love to have any other suggestions please. Thanks.

Comment: I came across this [project](https://github.com/uberspot/2048-android) look at the asset directory of the project. what I am saying is that your share_component should be another repo and should link inside both of your other directories. As far as usage is concerned let someone else manage **shared_component** repo

Comment: this can scale and you ask everyone to treat **shared_components** as another directory/repo.

Comment: Doesn't that add extra complexity into the project when the submodule repo is updated? And also I have read from several places about avoiding git submodules at all cost. If there is a particular way you think is best to work with them please let me know. Thanks.

Comment: well it'll add some complexity into the project but it'll keep everything consistent for every one. managing the new repo/sumodule will not be much of a hassle as everyone will be pretty much developing on there own branch say **mobile and desktop** and will have there version of the code/environment. and scalability will be achieved.

Comment: ok @MubashirHanif I am considering git submodules but I am still not fully convinced especially because of the bad name that submodules currently has. I mean every article I read about it (even the ones that talk about how to use submodules) all talk about the pitfalls, traps, hair-pullings, that come with submodules. I'm not sure I would want to get all that. Would try checking for best practices to follow when using submodules. Thanks,

Comment: @MubashirHanif so I have just gone through quite a number of articles on git submodules and honestly, I would rather go a different route. There's just too much complexity and a lot of chances for error in the process.

Comment: they Worked for me pretty good. May be because I am a bit more familiar with git and VCing in general. Best of luck for your project though.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [Google Repo](https://code.google.com/p/git-repo/). It's a tool build on top of git used by Google to make their Android repositories easier to manage. It's open source so you can use it for your own projects.